How to use JSONLoader for complex json files in langchain?
I have a complex JSON structure that will use a format similar to following.
{
"data" : {
    "Country": "USA",
    "Source": "ABC",
    "Company Summary": {
      "Company Name": "ABC Networks Co.,Ltd.",
      "Company Code": "111222",
      "Main Office Address": "9, California",
      "Telephone": "",
      "Telephone2": "",
      "Register kept by": "USA BANK",
      "Ending Month of FY": "12",
      "Establishment Date": "2000.02.10",
      "Newspaper(s) used For major notices": "BUSINESS NEWSPAPER",
      "Employees": "500",
      "Listing Date": "2015.08.21"
    }
    ,
    "more-data": "..."
}

I create a vector store with the following code. But I can't use JSONLoader since specifying loader_kwargs={'jq_schema': '.data'} will give an error saying this field is not an string. I do not want to specify one field since all fields are containing important data separately.
loader = DirectoryLoader(DATA_PATH, glob='**/*.json', loader_cls=JSONLoader,
                         loader_kwargs={'jq_schema': '.data'}) # this gives an error
documents = loader.load()
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=150)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name='sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2',
                                       model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})
db = FAISS.from_documents(texts, embeddings)
db.save_local(DB_FAISS_PATH)

How can I properly introduce my data to JSONLoader and use for above?
